# C++ boost::regex_match gives all NULLs results

Tags: c++, boost-regex

I am facing a weird problem which is boost::regex_match gives all NULLs results.

Sorry for the bad problem description. Let me copy and paste the code below.

I think the boost lib version should be Boost 1-47-0. GCC 4.3.2 on Linux.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/regex.hpp>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string aFreeText = "26JAN07";
    boost::regex expression("([0-9]{2}[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{2})");
    boost::smatch results;

    if(boost::regex_match(aFreeText, results, expression))
    {
        for(int index=0; index<results.size(); index++)
            DEBUG("YI JI results[" << index << "].str(): " << results[index].str());
    }

    return 0;
}
```

However, in the log, the display is very weird.

[image]

Can anyone kindly help me with this problem? Your kind help will be greatly appreciated.

If the provided information is not enough, please feel free to leave your comment and I will add them later.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine with Boost 1.55, GCC 4.9.2 on Windows 7 (64 Bits)

It could be a problem with your boost installation

The code below produces the following result (as you expected)

```
$ ./re.exe 
Results[0].str(): 26JAN07
```

C++ code: `re.cpp`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/regex.hpp>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string aFreeText = "26JAN07";
    boost::regex expression("[0-9]{2}[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{2}");
    boost::smatch results;
    if(boost::regex_match(aFreeText, results, expression))
    {
        for(size_t index=0; index<results.size(); ++index)
        {
            std::cout<<"Results[" << index << "].str(): " << results[index].str()<<std::endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The `CMakeLists.txt` used looks like

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.8.8)
PROJECT(RE)

#############################################################################
SET(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS   ON)
SET(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED OFF)
FIND_PACKAGE(Boost 1.53 COMPONENTS regex REQUIRED)
#############################################################################
IF (NOT(MSVC))
    SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=gnu++0x")
ENDIF()

ADD_EXECUTABLE(re re.cpp)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(SYSTEM ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(re ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

Comment: Many thanks for your quick reply. If this is the case, I guess I need to find some alternative solution to this problem. :(

Comment: You should try this code, and see if it is causing the same problem.